# How to remove a book from iBooks

Tags: icloud, books

I "bought" a free book on iBooks Store, the book is on my iCloud.
Now I would to remove it, but I cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: have you tried selecting it and hitting the delete key?

Comment: @amergin: yes, no way.

Comment: I have the same problem. It can't be removed. Logic is that when one "buy" something electronically, it can't be thrown away. It's in list of your purchases remaining there forever. You can just hide it.

Comment: This is very annoying. I also have quite some free books I "bought" that sit in my iBooks and there is no way to permanently delete them. Some book titles are very embarrassing and I'd like to have those completely removed. I am not looking for hide and unhide. Any solutions?

Comment: That's hide only. My research seems to tell me there is no way to delete any.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

- On a Mac, open the iBooks app.
- Go to the iBooks Store (left of the toolbar, at the top).
- On the right-hand-side, in the Quick Links list, click the Purchased link.
- Books will appear; find the one you want to remove and hover your mouse over the cover.
- A little 'x' will appear; click it to remove the book.

The book will no longer come up in iBooks (or any other locations), no matter whether you have set iBooks to show or hide iCloud items.

Comment: It sounds like this process requires a Mac? How does one do this on an iPad/iPhone? Some books on my iPad have the "Delete" button greyed out. lauhub describes a way to "hide" them on iPad, but perhaps only a Mac can delete them permanently?

Comment: I can't see a way of doing it on iOS, unfortunately.

Comment: This only *hides* the book but does not delete it.

Answer (score 7):

Under iOS, it is possible to achieve the same thing according to [this page](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/ibooks-for-ios-hiding-icloud-books)

1. Open the iBooks app.
2. Tap "My Books" at the bottom of the screen.
3. Tap "All Books" in the middle of the upper bar.
4. Switch on "Hide iCloud Books" at the bottom of the screen.

That's it !

Answer (score 1):

First, delete the local copy by selecting it and pressing `delete` and then confirming by pressing the "Delete" button in the confirmation dialog.

Now if the book is displaying with the iCloud icon you can hide the iCloud purchases,  by clicking on the "Sort By" menu and making sure "Show Purchases in iCloud" is unchecked. If that was already unchecked, then the book's icon will simply disappear.

Comment: a bug or a feature? :)

Comment: It's definitely intentional, so I'd call it a feature.

Comment: I already found how to remove the local copy and how to hide the iCloud copies, but I would to *remove* the iCloud copies. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac you can tick `Menu > View > Hide purchases` (I work on a Dutch system, so I hope this is correct); on iOS you can do this in `Preferences > iBooks > Show all purchases`.

You can hide all unwanted books in iTunes on the Mac forever…

Comment: The OP was asking about iBooks, not iTunes. iTunes in Mavericks only deals with audiobooks, not PDF files or iBooks purchases.

Comment: This is simply not true:-) if I open iTunes on the Mac and view my purchases, I can view all my purchased books and hide them. If you prefer iBooks on the Mac, you can do exactly the same thing from the iBooks Store > Purchases tab.

Comment: I think I found what the OP was looking for. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, what worked for me was:  ibooks / library / choose the view=pdf's or books (note that pdf are always downloaded but books can be in app store aka cloud only)  / click button on right 'select' / choose one or more books to remove / click 'delete' / choose the kind of deletion. I choosed keep in cloud and just remove the download.
This just saved me almost a GB.

Answer (score -1):

To Delete a book from  the iBook library :

1. Click on iBooks
2. Click on the desired book you want deleted (But be sure the book does not pop up )
3. Now right click , Click on delete

Now The Book Is Deleted

Comment: For books on iCould there is no *Delete* in the pop-up menu.